# foreach two arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays like this

```
$slike = Array('artist2-1.jpg', 'artist2-2.jpg', 'artist2-3.jpg', 'artist2-4.jpg');
$slikethumb = Array('artist2-1_thumb.jpg',
                    'artist2-2_thumb.jpg',
                    'artist2-3_thumb.jpg',
                    'artist2-4_thumb.jpg');
```

When I `foreach` two arrays I want to get this output on view

```
echo'<a href='.$slike.'><img src='.$slikethumb.'></a>';
```

I know how to `foreach` one array, but what I have to do to combine two arrays in one foreach?

Comment: Use a for loop from `$i = 0` to `$i <= count($slike)`

Comment: If the two arrays are intrinsically and logically linked, they should be one array, just multi-dimensional. Far easier to work with and iterate over.

Comment: Ok, can you write a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:*

Considering your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654293/substr-from-end-of-string-php), You might want to think about scanning your directoy using `glob` and a more specific pattern, something along the lines of:

```
$sLike = glob('{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.jpg',GLOB_BRACE);
//selects all .jpg files with names ending with number.jpg, so no _thumb.jpg files
```

Then, with this in mind and in light of your comment. How to remove the file extensions:

```
$sLike = array();//the array from dir scan
$clean = array();
foreach($sLike as $file)
{
    $clean[] = substr($file, 0, strpos($file, '.')*-1);//get file name
}
$format = '<a href="%s.jpg"><img src="%1$s_thumb.jpg" /></a>';//output format
foreach($clean as $like)
{
    printf($format, $like);
}
```

Or, with a more liberal pattern used for the `glob` call, and if you want to go with option 2 (the one with different extensions per file):

```
$sLike = array();//the array from dir scan
$clean = array();
foreach($sLike as $file)
{
    $endOffset = strpos($file, '.')*-1;
    $clean[] = array(
        substr($file, 0, $endOffset),//get file name
        substr($file,$endOffset)//get extension, includes the . char!
    );
}
$format = '<a href="%s%s"><img src="%1$s_thumb%2$s" /></a>';//output format
foreach($clean as $like)
{
    echo vsprintf($format, $like);
}
```

That's about it...

---

What I'd do is use but a single array. The base string is the same for both images:

```
$slike=array(
        'artist2-1',
        'artist2-2',
        'artist2-3',
        'artist2-4'
);//remove extensions
$format = '<a href="%s.jpg"><img src="%1$s_thumb.jpg" /></a>';//output format
foreach($slike as $like)
{
    printf($format, $like);
}
```

That will give you what you want, without there ver being a need for 2 arrays, as you can see [on **this codepad**](http://codepad.org/vLZJnEB0).
Benefits of this approach:

- only constructs 1 array, not 2
- uses `printf` which translates internally to a `fprintf(stdout, "<your format>", zval*$like);` in C, which is fast.
- No excess fat: there's very little repetition. You could even change the format to `artist2-%s.jpg"><img src="artist2-%s_thumb.jpg" />`, and only stores the numbers in the array, but that's taking it absurdly far.
- Short, and concise code

Of course, there are caveats:

- less readable & maintainable code
- If ever you add 1 image with a different extension (png), you'll have to refactor...

The choice is yours. If different extensions is likely to happen, you could change the code above to something like:

```
$slike=array(
        array('artist2-1','jpg'),
        array('artist2-2','png'),
        array('artist2-3','gif'),
        array('artist2-4','jpeg'),
);//remove extensions

$format = '<a href="%s.%s"><img src="%1$s_thumb.%2$s" /></a>';//output format
foreach($slike as $like)
{
    echo vsprintf($format, $like);
}
```

As you can see [on **this codepad**](http://codepad.org/6kbC04AY), that'll work like a charm, too

Comment: @Gorostas: If you're going to use this answer, would you kindly accept this answer (if you don't mind my asking)...

Comment: Please edit your code to remove extension from array, and i will accept :)

Comment: @Gorostas: What extensions? The array values don't contain the extensions, because the file extensions are constant, so they needn't be part of the array values

Comment: Please remove extension .jpg from array, make new array, i think that is the best solution?

Comment: @Gorostas: But the values of the `$sLike` array don't _have_ the .jpg extension in my first snippet, they never had! Those extensions are part of the format. They're written once, and used throughout. My second example is a tad more elaborate, but it allows for all extensions imaginable to be used

Comment: But @Elias I have array that is reading files from directory :)

Answer (score 4):

If those arrays are sorted correctly and both have same number of elements:

```
foreach($slike as $i => $value){
    echo'<a href='.$value.'><img src='.$slikethumb[$i].'></a>'; 
}
```

Comment: Correction: $slikethumb[i] should be $slikethumb[$i]

Answer (score 1):

If same number of elements in both array & sorted then,

```
foreach($slikethumb as $key => $val) {
  echo '<a href='.$slike[$key].'><img src='.$val.'></a>';
}
```

Comment: but +1, for the fast answer :D

Comment: On this way i get echo like this?? <a href="artist2-4_thumb.jpg"><img src="artist2-4_thumb.jpg"></a>

Comment: Thumb on a href and on source?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop

```
for($i = 0; $i< count($slike); $i++)
{
   $slike_val      = $slike[$i];
   $slikethumb_val = $slikethumb[$i];
   echo'<a href='.$slike_val.'><img src='.$slikethumb_val.'></a>';
}
```

Comment: I am assuming both arrays are of same size and are sorted in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
You will try 

foreach($slike as $key=>$slike_val)
echo'<a href='.$slike_val.'><img src='.$slikethumb[$key].'></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($slike as $key=>$img) {
   print '<a href='.$img.'><img src='.$slikethumb[$key].'></a>';
}
```

Or if you want one which is not based on the ordering....

```
foreach ($slike as $key=>$img) {
   list($name, $ext)=explode('.', $img);
   $thumb=$name . '_thumb.' . $ext;
   if (in_array($thumb, $slikethumb)) {
       print '<a href='.$img.'><img src='.$thumb.'></a>';
   } else {
       ...?
   }
}
```

Comment: exploding all strings (constructing an array), then concatenating a new string for each image is just a lot of work. If you're passing the string to `print`, why not use `printf` and have the `_thumb` bit be part of the format in the first place (as I did in my answer)...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
        $slike = array('artist2-1.jpg', 'artist2-2.jpg', 'artist2-3.jpg', 'artist2-4.jpg');

        $slikethumb = array('artist2-1_thumb.jpg', 'artist2-2_thumb.jpg', 'artist2-3_thumb.jpg', 'artist2-4_thumb.jpg');

        foreach($slike as $key1 => $value1)
        {
            echo $value1."--------->".$slikethumb[$key1]."<br />";
        }
        ?>
```

- Thanks